# Contact Form 7 - Multiple input with the same name (array name)

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am developing this form that has the functionality that allow the user to add an input field in the form. Here's the input field that will be added:

```
<li>
    <input type="text" name="appliSkill[]" placeholder="Adobe Photoshop" >
</li>
```

I am using contact form 7 plugin to handle the the submission and email process of this for.

For a simple input name, we can easily call the **[input-name]** in the mail section of the cf7 to pass the value of that field and send it through email.

I would like to do the same and get all the value of **appliSkill[]** and pass it to the email. Assuming the form would be look like this after the user add more fields:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <input type="text" name="appliSkill[]" placeholder="Adobe Photoshop" >
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="text" name="appliSkill[]" placeholder="Adobe Photoshop" >
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="text" name="appliSkill[]" placeholder="Adobe Photoshop" >
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="text" name="appliSkill[]" placeholder="Adobe Photoshop" >
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can i do that?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can use any repeater field and at the time of submitting the form just bind the all the repeater field values then send the mail.

Comment: I am new with this plugin, technically, how will i do that in cf7?

Comment: Just use any jQuery repeater field to make the fields repeatable and then bind the final data using hooks you'll find it on google.